# purpose of app.component.ts (AppComponent) in ng2?

Tags: angular

Is an AppComponent class required for ng2 apps?  Ng2 is component-driven but I was wondering if a component specifically named AppComponent is required. Is ng2 specifically wired up to start its flow in a class named AppComponent?

Comment: thanks rashfmnb that provides clarity.  do you guess that the vast majority of ng2 architects use the default name of "AppComponent"?  seems like the name is fairly general and descriptive and provides a familiar convention to future devs who may be maintaining the app.

Comment: thanks rash if you want to add your comments as an answer then I'll mark it as answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can change the name to `MyComponent` and use it while bootstrap

```
bootstrap(MyComponent, [...]).catch(err => console.error(err));
```

Answer (score 1):

This is not required to use **AppComponent** name, but its **recommended one**. Every angular app should have one component which can be boostrapped which is **AppComponent** (which can have different name too).

There are some guide lines provided by Angular2 Team. You can have a look here - https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/style-guide.html . This is indirectly related to your question not directly.